# "Don't walk. Run." tag

Tags: discussion, tags

In the spirit of JeffE's frequent answer, do we need a "Don't walk. Run." tag. It really is such a simple and great answer and I could imagine wanting to easily find all the questions about things that should be run away from.

Comment: I'm not sure it's in the spirit of SE tags, but I like the idea :)

Comment: In the end this can cover everything in academia, if the advice was followed by enough people this would lead to lots of people running (probably in circles, while screaming) with no certain direction until they fall out of academia (for the good or for the bad). I think we would also need a tag: "Keep calm and ___" to compensate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I like JeffE's "Don't walk. Run." phrase too.

However, it is not a good candidate for a tag as:

- it describes an answer, not a questions,
- it is a subjective, meta-tag.

On the other hand, IMHO adding a tag like [personal-conflicts](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-conflicts) or [interpersonal-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpersonal-issues) would be beneficial.

Comment: I agree (except for the first sentence).  I like JeffE's "Don't walk. Run." comment.  But I don't see the relevance of making it a tag.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Sorry, I meant "I like [...] _phrase_ too.". Clarified.

Comment: I think "[tag:abuse]" would be a better choice for tag.

Comment: Also, wouldn't we then have to delineate "Don't walk, run.", "Don't walk. Run." and "Don't walk. RUN!!!" tags?